# PowerShell Cmdlet development : best practice regarding IEnumerable that is piped between Cmdlets

Tags: powershell, pipe, powershell-cmdlet

Let's say you have two Cmdlets : the first one returns output and the second one uses that output as an input parameter.

```
public class Cmdlet1 : PSCmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        List<string> result = ...
        WriteObject(result, true);
    }
}

public class Cmdlet2 : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public string Input { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        // Do a long operation on Input.
    }
}
```

Cmdlet2 will be invoked multiple times this way (once for every element in the IEnumerable that Cmdlet1 returns) and you can nicely pipe them together : Cmdlet1 | Select-Object -First 10 | Cmdlet2
Only the first 10 elements of Cmdlet1's output get send to Cmdlet2.

Because Cmdlet2 takes some time, it would be nice to display progress. Currently we can't do that because we only receive the Input strings one by one. Let's change the input of Cmdlet2 to a List

```
public class Cmdlet1 : PSCmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        List<string> result = ...
        WriteObject(result, true);
    }
}

public class Cmdlet2 : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public List<string> Input { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        // Do a long operation on Input.
    }
}
```

We still get the input strings one by one, because the WriteObject call in Cmdlet1 has true as a second parameter, allowing PowerShell to enumerate the result to individual objects. If we change that to false, PowerShell doesn't enumerate the result and Cmdlet2 gets the entire list of strings as input and we can operate on all strings and display a nice progress bar.

```
public class Cmdlet1 : PSCmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        List<string> result = ...
        WriteObject(result, false);
    }
}

public class Cmdlet2 : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public List<string> Input { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        // Do a long operation on Input, displaying a progress bar.
    }
}
```

BUT : now we can't easily pipe them anymore.
Cmdlet1 | Select-Object -First 10 | Cmdlet2 now sends the entire input to Cmdlet2! The Select-Object doesn't take the first 10 because there is only 1 element that is an IEnumerable and that element is completely sent to Cmdlet2!

What is the proper way to deal with a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

Move your long running operation to the `EndProcessing` block, use `ProcessRecord` to aggregate the input:

```
public class Cmdlet2 : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = true)]
    public string[] InputObject { get; set; }

    private List<string> inputList = new List<string>();

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        inputList.AddRange(InputObject);
    }

    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < inputList.Count; i++)
        {
            this.WriteProgress(new ProgressRecord(1, "Doing long running operation", $"Currently processing item {i+1} / {inputList.Count}"));
            DoLongRunningOperation(inputList[i]);
        }
    }
}
```